# Переработка OOP кода в MVC паттерн

Tags: ооп, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Я изучаю MVC. Знаю, что существует множество реализаций. Но для меня остаются неясными с связи между различными его составляющими, при появлении других контроллерв, моделей и отображений. 
Например, могу ли я вызывать любой компонент MVC из службы? Контроллер должен так же может выполнять функции типа void, которые могут вызываться из других скриптов, почему в фреймворке CodeIgniter нельзя вызвать контроллер из другого контроллера и тд.?
Для того, чтобы лучше разобраться в этом. Возможно мне поможет переработанный пример кода в ООП стиле на MVC. 
Я хотел бы знать, как можно переработать этот класс Car для отображения в шаблоне MVC? И как будут реализованы связи, если я захочу использовать методы Go() и Stop() из любого скрипта? Я хочу, чтобы эти методы работали при нажатии клавиши на клавиатуре и так же нажатии кнопки на экране. Кроме того, через некоторое время после вызова метода Go() должен сработать метод Stop().
public Car myCar;

```
static void Main()
{
    myCar = new Car("BMW", 2009, "Black");
}

public class KeyInput() {
    private void OnPressKeyG() {
        myCar.Go();
    }
}

public class CarButton() {
    public void OnClickButtonGo() {
        myCar.Go();
    }
}

public class Car {
    private string _model;
    private int _yearBuy;
    private string _color;
    public Car(model, yearBuy, color) {
        this._model = model;
        this._yearBuy = _yearBuy;
        this._color = _color;
    }
    public void Go() {
        // Go.    
    }
    public void Stop() {
        // Stop.    
    }
    public void ChangeColor(newColor) {
        _color = newColor;
    }
    private void DelayStop() { // Some delay.         
        Go();
    }
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

MVC - это идеология. Никаких жёстких рамок для его использования нет, в общем то: поэтому в детали не обязательно углубляться, как вы решите у себя в проекте, такие взаимодействия и будут разрешены.

> Например, могу ли я вызывать любой компонент MVC из службы? Контроллер
> должен так же может выполнять функции типа void, которые могут
> вызываться из других скриптов, почему в фреймворке CodeIgniter нельзя
> вызвать контроллер из другого контроллера и тд.?

Вызов контроллером другого контроллера - в Zend для этого есть forward (то есть перебросить выполнение, из одного контроллера, на другой) очень удобно, например для вывода ошибок, или наоборот сообщений об успехе.

Или у вас есть контроллер, например, для регистрации юзеров - а вам надо из другого контроллера зарегать их 1000: нужно в цикле сконструировать контроллер регистрации, объекты запроса, ответа, и выполнять. Или даже не конструируя, выполнить действия контроллера через curl (http-запросы на свой-же сервис). Сам так делал, обоими способами.

Но лучше этим не злоупотреблять - потому что контроллер таким образом превратится в сборник функций. А он должен представлять собой сборник законченных действий для внешних пользователей вашего сервиса (то есть для web-клиента, если мы про web), как API. Переиспользуемые же внутри кода функции: гораздо лучше смотрятся в моделях, а также в других вспомогательных классах, утилитах.

> хотел бы знать, как можно переработать этот класс Car для отображения
> в шаблоне MVC?

Класс-пример, который вы предлагаете переработать - очень неудачный: по сути, это и есть модель, буква M из словосочетания MVC . Вам нужно взять что-то в пример из областей, где реально используется MVC - из веба, а абстрактную фантазию из серии "как натянуть ужа на ежа" мало кому охота включать . Но я попробую.

Допустим ваша машина живёт в web (язык бекенда PHP, коде-игнитер вроде пхп ведь). Тогда все её данные хранятся где-то например в БД , или в файле на сервере; _model _yearBuy _color - конкретно они будут принадлежать модели M. Контроллер C - будет разбит на действия GoAction и StopAction . При вызове метода GoAction с запланированной остановкой - может происходить просто вызов метода модели Go($stopSeconds), а в нём уже:

```
$this->engineWorking = true;
$this->stopTimestamp = time() + $stopSeconds;
$this->save();
/*Важно - модель никогда не использует переменные напрямую из запроса 
- нужные переменные подсовывает в аргументы метода модели сам контроллер.*/
```

Контроллер C также передаёт данные о машине в вид.

```
$this->view->carData = $car->toArray();
```

Вид V(в данном случае - один на 2 экшена контроллера), простой html c PHP-вставками, соответственно рендерит всё, что происходит: состояние машины. В его JS выводится

```
var carData = <?=json_encode($this->carData)?>;
```

Также он понимает точку отсчёта времени:

```
var serverTime = <?=time()?>;
```

Чтобы корректно отрендерить запланированную остановку(переключить состояние кнопок по наступлению `stopTimestamp`). А также содержит в себе две кнопки Поехали и Стоп. В зависимости от того, едет машина, или стоит - можно нажать одну из этих двух кнопок. Cостояние кнопок может поменяться без участия юзера - по наступлению `stopTimestamp`.

Нажатие кнопки вызывает ajax-запрос, который направляется на StopAction или на GoAction , после чего страница, например, перезагружается (меняет весь свой HTML на то, что вернул ajax).

Вот и всё. Но это слишком игрушечный пример - на таком вы не сможете понять, зачем нужен MVC . На гитхабе, наверняка, есть проекты - количество экшенов в сумме под 500 , и количество моделей под 100 : вот вам надо развернуть такой, и плотно поиздеваться над ним. Вся суть в том - что контроллеры независимы друг от друга - а вся связь между ними, идёт через ссылки/скрипты видов(которые дёргают эти контроллеры по http), то есть **вся связь между контроллерами идёт через пользовательские действия**. И виды так-же независимы друг друга. Модели часто связаны, но лишь внутри своих методов, и глобальной системы кеширования у фреймворка. В итоге, вам очень сложно что-то сломать во всей системе, если вы правите один контроллер, или один вид, или даже модель( при этом следуя правилу Лискин - модифицируй так, чтобы старое работало неизменно ). Как устроены классы, дело десятое, как нравится вам/фреймворку их вообще может не быть в MVC (или по минимуму - только для моделей), и MVC будет работать.

И никто не запрещает пользоваться при MVC вспомогательными классами , как например утилиты, диспетчеры событий, классы для форм(валидация/рендеринг), общие функции для контроллеров - которые не ассоциируются с БД, и.т.д.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за такой развернутый ответ!
Идея не связанности скриптов мне нравится,  но при разработке проекта (js) столкнулся большой проблемой. Я передаю инфу через http запрос, но данных много и не хочется засорять поле url лишний раз. Тогда я начал слать ивенты, но код становится на столько запутанным, что хочется вернуться к связям снова..

Comment: и еще пример с регистрацией юзеров, я не понял что имеется ввиду под контроллером регистрации

Comment: @Eugenio Uglov совершенно не знаю, что у вас за проект, и соответственно ничего понять не могу - необходимость передавать много лишних данных в запросах. Классика - бекенд ведает данными, JS получает только то, что ему надо, чтобы отобразить всё корректно. Ну а контроллер регистрации - я даже не знаю, как по другому назвать это. Вот есть у вас на сайте пользователи, значит есть и действие регистрации - контроллер регистрации содержит метод для этого действия.

Comment: для меня самым сложным является понять как без связей между контроллерами можно вызывать методы упорядоченно между ними относящиеся к одному и тому же запросу. Из моего проекта класса - noteController и noteSpeakerController (класс, как расширение первого, но с дополнительными возможностями). noteSpeakerController  может не существовать, но он обязательно должен выполнять методы speakerController. Итак я получаю http запрос в noteSpeakerController, мне нужно отобразить информацию - дело noteController и выполнить остальное из спикера. Как их можно связать?

Comment: Кроме того если я буду в обоих контроллерах обрабатывать один и тот же запрос, тк первый может работать не зависимо от второго, то можно схватить асинхрон. А мне нужно обрабатывать по очереди, в зависимости от того подключен второй скрипт или нет

Comment: @Eugenio Uglov очень просто связывать - noteController и noteSpeakerController , это должно находиться в одном контроллере.  Должен быть только noteController , в который вы передаёте параметр, например ?use_speaker_functionality=1 . Не знаю, контроллеры состоят у вас из действий, или контроллер и есть у вас действие - но в любом случае, контроллеры разделяются - если в них сильно разнится смысл, стек используемых моделей. Если один, лишь модификация другого: добавляются параметры, хоть 10. Иначе вы делаете плохую вещь в коде - размножаете понятия(классы, итп.) на пустом месте.

Comment: тут просто такое дело, что noteSpeakerController это как расширение. Не хотелось бы смешивать две разные сущности. Потому что может быть еще к примеру noteHiglihtController, noteBigTextController. А сам код хранится в базе данных пользователя (независимого разработчика).